# Using last inserted id in mysql multi query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, last-insert-id, mysqli-multi-query

I am trying to use last inserted id in MySQL muli_query but I don't know what I missed

this is my code :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts 
                    (nparc,id_chauffeur,id_camion,
                     lot_de_bord,triangle,pelle,balai,date)
            values('$nparc','$id_chauffeur','$id_camion',
                    '$lot_de_bord','$triangle', '$pelle', 
                    '$balai','$get_datetime');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO photos
                        (post_id,64_image1, 64_image2, 64_image3, 
                         64_image4 ,date_upload)
                values('$mysqli->insert_id','$imsrc1','$imsrc2',
                       '$imsrc3','$imsrc4','$get_datetime');";

$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) ;
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: @treyBake can you tell me where and how . thank you

Comment: [How to prevent against SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Have you confirmed what `$mysqli->insert_id` returns?

Comment: You might be better creating a transaction for this and executing 2 seperate queries wrapped in commit/rollback

Comment: `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);` here is the link : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp scroll page down to procedural.

Comment: @OualidOukassou the whole query - and check the link Mark put in :)

Comment: @Dilek never recommend w3schools for PHP - it's a terrible resource that's out of date and full of bad practices

Comment: @Dilek Beware of w3fools, it is not respected around here. Also check [The manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) for how to get this info using OOP

Comment: @treyBake well its your tought! its a usefull site to me, they have all type of codes, prepared statements, object, pdo etc.. its up to users what they want to do with and which they want to use.

Comment: @Dilek [there's a manual](https://www.php.net/) from PHP themselves - much better resource. All of what you mention is included there - and you're right, it is up to the user, but much better to learn properly

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont see the difference `mysqli_insert_id($link);` but I will refer to php site now on.

Comment: You can't use it like this. You're creating the query string, then inserting it. Unless you've already run a query, `$mysqli->insert_id` won't exist when you create the string. You'd be better off using transactions and running this as two queries.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This would not work with `mysqli_multi_query`. This function is too broken. Yet another reason not to use it.

Comment: @aynber makes a Very Good Point.

Comment: @Dharman Got to close to the problem :) Maybe the OP should follow [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898046/using-last-inserted-id-in-mysql-multi-query#comment105923623_59898046)

Comment: If you want to use it as one multi_query, you might want to try [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) instead.

Comment: With his codes it should be like this `if ($connection->multi_query($query) === TRUE) { $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); echo $last_id;` anything else wont work.

Comment: @Dilek - That won't work since they need the last insert id as a value in the second query.

Comment: @aynber thank you for helping
must use LAST_INSERT_ID()  instead of $mysqli->insert_id .
can admin flag this like good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `mysqli_multi_query()`. It is never recommended to use.

What you are probably looking for are transactions. You can execute both statements as prepared statements inside of a transaction.

```
try {
    $connection->begin_transaction();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO posts 
    (nparc,id_chauffeur,id_camion,lot_de_bord,triangle,pelle,balai,date)
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $nparc, $id_chauffeur, $id_camion, $lot_de_bord, $triangle, $pelle, $balai, $get_datetime);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO photos
    (post_id, 64_image1, 64_image2, 64_image3, 64_image4 ,date_upload)
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $connection->insert_id, $imsrc1, $imsrc2, $imsrc3, $imsrc4, $get_datetime);
    $stmt->execute();

    $connection->commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $connection->rollback();
}
```

Make sure that you have error reporting enabled otherwise your code won't work. You must put this line before `new mysqli()`

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Tought prepared statements are better because of adding values on their types, No ? Your example inserting all Data as string, ids is well.

Comment: @Dilek The types don't matter. What matters is that you bind the data separately.

Comment: @Dilek I have to insert integer values too .

Comment: @oualid Integers are strings too.

Comment: @OualidOukassou integers `i`, string `s`, more : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php or do what dharman said

Comment: @Dharman well you are wrong on that I think, that will cause problems if he validate integer as a value example `intval(sss);`.  or `/^[0-9]*$/` with a regepx OualidOukassou following php refers is beter always.

Comment: @Dilek If you can show me an example where it actually causes a problem it would be great. You could also ask another question on stack overflow about it.

Comment: @Dharman you got answer in my previus comment here is another, try to validate string with this function : `function filterNum($numbers){
    if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$numbers) === false){
  return $numbers;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}` I dont need to as a question I think.lol my question is very clear validate a string with the function in this comment.

Comment: @dilek I don't understand you. Please ask a question if you have doubts about my recommendation. Comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: how can i check if result or if the transaction are complete

Comment: @oualid Please ask another question if you have a new problem.